# Look around markdown regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to do a custom markdown notation and I need the inner most markdown every time, At the moment I have only 2 markdowns for testing purposes `_` and `*`

Regex:
`(?<![_\*])(?<!\\)\*(?![_\*])(([^\*]|\\\*)*)(?<![_\*])(?<!\\)\*`
for capturing the inner most `*`

Examples:

1. Should capture: `*test1\*test2*` - Captures!
2. Should capture: `_*test1\*test2*_` - but doesn't Capture because of the next rule.
3. Shouldn't capture: `*_test1\*test2_* some random text *` - Doesn't Capture `*_test1\*test2_*` and captures `* some random text *` but I want to ignore this capture.

If I remove my first look before `(?<![_\*])` works for 1 and 2, but captures the last `*` from the text until the next one because the beginning `*` is from from the previous text which should be ignored

Comment: Can you be more specific about what rules your regex needs to enforce?

Comment: Is "parse Markdown with Regex" the new "[parse HTML with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/121493)"?

Comment: I want to capture the inner most markdown and ignoring the escaped ones. But if it's not the inner most I want to ignore the last markdown as well I've edited the post and tried to explain it better.

Comment: Maybe you want ``\*(?!\s)([^\\*_\n]*(?:\\.[^\\*_\n]*)*)(?<!\s)\*``? See https://regex101.com/r/JpGhAW/1

Comment: Yes, that's good but I doesn't work with `* test *`, but I think I can work with this.

Comment: I just realized that I actually need the outer most markdown, not the inner most :(

Comment: I think that's it `(?<!\\)(?<![_\*])\*(?!\s)([^\\\*\n]+(?:\\.[^\\\*\n]*)*)\*(?![_\*])`. Thanks for your help.